# Set Vim plugin options in a NeoVim init.lua

Tags: lua, neovim

I want to set vim plugin options that have the vimscript format `let some#option = option` inside my NeoVim `init.lua` file, but I can't figure out how to set these options in a format that NeoVim respects.

I've tried using `vim.cmd("let some#option = option")` but this doesn't seem to work. Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [nanotee/nvim-lua-guide](https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide), the section on [Managing vim internal variables](https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide#managing-vim-internal-variables) shows various API calls, including

- Global variables (`g:`):

  - [`vim.api.nvim_set_var()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_set_var())
  - [`vim.api.nvim_get_var()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_get_var())
  - [`vim.api.nvim_del_var()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_del_var())

In practice, setting a global variable looks like

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_var('some#var', 'value')
```

You can also use the [meta-accessors](https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide#using-meta-accessors-1), such as [`vim.g`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html#vim.g):

```lua
vim.g['some#var'] = 'value'
```

---

The method with `vmd.cmd` can work, although using the more structured API shown above is advised.

Note that in `vim.cmd("let some#option = option")` the right-hand side of the assignment operator is an *expression*. This means the plain token `option` would be evaluated as an identifier.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you may need to add additional quotes to create a string.

```lua
vim.cmd("let some#var = 'value'")
```